# How to get OSM xml or json data from an url?

Tags: api, url, dictionary

I have been working on twitter api and found it easy to get json/xml feed from an url like

http://twitter.com/friends/ids.json?screen_name=Planemad&jsoncallback=?

similarly i wanted to know if there is a way to get OSM json/xml data from an url and use that and use it on an OSM map....

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_Protocol_Version_0.6

There is possibilities to read data in specific bounding box (however not too much).